# Safety stock calculation

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am trying to calculate a optimal [safety stock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safety_stock) based on time-series analysis of the sales and the previous lead times of the suppliers.

For that purpose, I am using the classical formula which is:

[image: classic formula]

That is based on the average and standard deviation of the two components, which are the forecasted demand and the lead time.

The forecasting is made using the `auto.arima` function of the `forecast` package in R.

The problem I am facing, is that I have the sales per day, and the lead times are also days, but if I try to input that directly to the auto.arima, the forecast is bad because there are a lot of days where sales are 0, and also doesn't get the yearly seasionality right.

So what I do is aggregate the sales monthly and forecast monthly, that gives good forecasts, but then to estimate the standard deviation everything has to be in the same time unit right?

So I split the monthly forecast equally amongst its days, which gives for example 20 units a day, then compare to the actual data to get the forecast error, and that is for example many days at 0 and one day 100, which as a result means high standard deviation of the error, and this leads to high safety stock values.

I think I am doing something wrong here when I forecast monthly and then compare the error on a daily basis. It feels statiscally incorrect, however I am not sure it is.

The other option I was thinking is converting lead times to months and use the formula with all the quantities in a monthly basis (I think forecast error in months will be relatively smaller), do you think it is a better choice?

Any other options I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Sparse sales data (many days with zero sales) is a well known problem in safety stock optimization. This pattern is often referenced to as **intermittent** or **erratic** demand.

This is a great post on how to design a demand prediction model for intermittent demand and use it to optimize safety stock - https://blog.griddynamics.com/safety-stock-optimization-for-ship-from-store/